# HTML5 Input pattern matching doesn't work, Rubular regex does

Tags: ruby, regex, html

Any thoughts as to why https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVbjGa:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="formField" title="Password must be at least eight characters in length, contain at least one capital letter, one number, and one special character." 
           pattern="\A(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*[\d]).{8,}\z" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

wouldn't work and http://rubular.com/r/9oIgojECMf would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace the beginning of the input `\A` with `^` and the end of input from `\z` to `$`

```html
<form>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="formField"
    title="Password must be at least eight characters in length, contain at least one capital letter, one number, and one special character." 
    pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*[\d]).{8,}"
    required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will accept answer as soon as I can!

Comment: @Drew You may consider that funny but you do not need any `^` and `$` - remove them and `pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*\d).{8,}"` will work the same.

Comment: There is no need to use `^` and `$` in the HTML5 `pattern` attribute regex, remove the anchors since they are added automatically by the engine.

Comment: You're right @WiktorStribiżew, I've updated the answer, thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `[W_]`  and `[d]` @Drew?

Comment: Sorry, removed that comment as I noticed the backslashes are somehow being stripped out with the generated HTML, but thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, happy coding @Drew ;)